# jQuery - Multiple functions bound to the same event

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, events

So jQuery behaves in a way such that if you assign multiple functions to the same event like this:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   console.log(1); 
});

$(window).load(function() {
   console.log(2); 
});
```

All of the functions will fire when something triggers this event.
On the other side, we have pure javascript with something like this:

```
window.onload = function() {
    console.log(3);
};
window.onload = function() {
    console.log(4);
};
```

Only the last assigned function will fire of course. 
Why does the jQuery behave that way? Are functions stacked somehow and fired in a row? Is this some fail-safe plan in case someone assigns multiple functions through code?

Comment: It's so that you *can* assign multiple handlers to events, which can be very useful.  You can name event handlers specifically (using a namespace) so that you can turn them off later, without turning off all handlers attached to the event.  It's a really nice way of doing things.

Comment: There's also `addEventListener` that you may have forgotten about, which exhibits the same behaviour as jQuery's wrapper functions.

Comment: Thank you very much for you replies. Didn't even knew there was something as namespace in event binds. Also thank you for reminding me on addEventListener function. I hate to use something while not knowing why and how it works :)